# searching multiple entity attributes in .net

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement broad searching functionality from my database. Let's say I have an entity that has multiple attributes such as: `Student` has `firstName`, `lastName`, `address`, etc...

What is the best way to search my database to find any record that has matching attributes?

```
var Result = _context.Student.Where(s => 
    s.firstName.Contains(query) 
    || s.lastName.Contains(query) 
    || s.address.Contains(query)))
    .ToList();
```

Is there a better and faster way to do the search?

Comment: Honestly, I'd probably start where you did and go with it until the performance became a problem.  I can think of a few marginally faster ways, but they all increase overhead in other areas.

Comment: I suggest if you have more request for this database query, then try indexing the columns for faster search.

Comment: i dont think that there is any, but if you have really big amount of data then you should try indexing the search result like google dose in a diffrent table. and also dont forget to use pagination, Take and Skip

Answer (score 1):

When you have lots of data, consider indexing.
Please check out those links:

[How does database indexing work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work)

[Search engine indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing)